# Leaflet fixed text label size

Tags: jquery, leaflet

hi i am trying to have multiple labels on a map. but when i zoom in and out, i would like the text to grow and shrink in size corresponding to the zooming.

Here is what i have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var map = L.map('map').setView([49.2, 16.5], 10);
  new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

  L.marker(new L.LatLng(49.2, 16.5), {
    icon: createLabelIcon("textLabelclass", "a place")
  }).addTo(map);
  L.marker(new L.LatLng(49.25, 16.4), {
    icon: createLabelIcon("textLabelclass", "another place")
  }).addTo(map);
  L.marker(new L.LatLng(49.15, 16.37), {
    icon: createLabelIcon("textLabelclass", "place 3")
  }).addTo(map);
  L.marker(new L.LatLng(49.21, 16.38), {
    icon: createLabelIcon("textLabelclass", "place 4")
  }).addTo(map);

})

var createLabelIcon = function(labelClass, labelText) {
  return L.divIcon({
    className: labelClass,
    html: labelText
  })
}
```

Comment: What does "_text to stay at a fixed size_" exactly mean to you? The code you show seems to place a div with text that keeps the same size in pixels irrespective of the map zoom, hence a "fixed" size.

Comment: yes apologies. I would like it to do the opposite, meaning: the text shrinks on zoom out and grows on zoom in.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you want text to be the part of the map. For example if you zoom out the whole map become smaller and you label become smaller too.

This is not an expected scenario for markers and icons because their size don't change on zoom.

But this is normal behavior for vector layers for example. So as a workaround you can make label using [SvgOverlay](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#svgoverlay).

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e4kf1z8g/) for details.

```
document.getElementById('map').style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';

const map = L.map("map").setView([48.86, 2.35], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

const svgElement = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
svgElement.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
svgElement.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 800 100');
svgElement.innerHTML = `
<rect width="800" height="100" fill="#ffffff"/>
<text x="0" y="80" style="font-size:6rem;">Some text here</text>
`;
const svgElementBounds = [[48.86 + 0.05, 2.35 + 0.03], [48.86 - 0.05, 2.35 -  0.03]];
const svg = L.svgOverlay(svgElement, svgElementBounds);

svg.addTo(map);
```